# I keep getting an error for illegal start of expression, throughout the beginning of each of my methods, what is wrong?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project to ask users which housing they would like to purchase and I'm getting several errors saying "illegal start of expression"

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Utility to take inputs from keyboard

public class RentingLab
{

    public static void main (String args[]) //main method
    {
       //code in the main method
    }



    {
    do //start of do while loop 

        if (option == 3) //if the user decides to select third option for housing purchase 
        {

            public static double price(double rentingPrice) //where the error for illegal start of expression is occurring 
            {
             //code in the method 
            }

        }
    //then more methods done in a similar fashion with "else if" statements
    while (option !=0);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First your loop must me in your main method. You can only create methods outside the main method. This means `public static double price(double rentingPrice)` must be outside your main mehtod. I suggest you follow some tutorials.

Comment: How am I supposed to have my methods in my do-while loop, if my do-while loop is within my main method? My other methods are currently outside of the main method.

Comment: You'll need to review the basic structure of a Class.  That should lead you to a proper way to organize your code, such as all methods being defined at the first level of your class.  Making all the action (like the do statement) happen inside of the main method.